# How do I customise a keyboard layout in Cinnamon / Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout, cinnamon

I can see in Cinnamon you can select a new keyboard layout in - start - keyboard - layouts.

But none of the layouts there match my new keyboard. 
How do I redefine a single key (differently placed backspace key that Linux thinks is a <)?

Comment: Or how to define a whole custom keyboard, I would like to know.